# Sporadic 500 error when accessing calling GetSecretAsync from webAPI

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-keyvault

we have a webapi, Azure SQL DB and keyvault hosted on azure.
Everything was fine until about a week back. 
We had to delete and recreate the resource group.
After this we started getting sporadic 500 "internal server error"
On debugging further we found that KeyVaultClient GetSecretAsync is throwing the below error:

2017-10-04 15:08:06:265 - [7664:40] - ERROR  - MyService.Helper.ConnectionFactory -

One or more errors occurred.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Common.KeyVaultReader.KeyVaultHelper.GetSecret(String secretName)
   at syngo.DataCloud.CD.Service.Helper.ConnectionFactory..ctor(IKeyVaultHelper keyVaultHelper)

But whats baffling is that the same code works if we deploy to another endpoint.
Even in the same deployment, it works for one set of GET/POST calls but fails for another.

I am at a loss on how to go about fixing it.

KeyvaultHelper GetSecret code below:

```
using (var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(GetToken))
{
  var secret = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    return await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(secretURI, secretName).ConfigureAwait(false);
  });
  return secret.Result.Value;
}
```

Update:

```
Aggregate exception as below:

2017-10-04 15:18:47:233 - [7664:86] - ERROR  - MyHelper.ExceptionHandling.GlobalExceptionLogger - WebAPI exception : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.42.136.180:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<SendAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__61.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Common.KeyVaultReader.KeyVaultHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<GetSecret>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Common.KeyVaultReader.KeyVaultHelper.GetSecret(String secretName)
   at Common.Authentication.Entitlement.EntitleAttribute.CheckFeatureSupported(String strToken, List`1 features)
   at System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.42.136.180:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<SendAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__61.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Common.KeyVaultReader.KeyVaultHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<GetSecret>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---
```

Comment: It would help if you setup better logging around that. It's probably throwing an `AggregateException`. That one contains the actual exception that caused it. If you put a try catch around that, which catches the AggregateException, you can log the inner exceptions from that.

Comment: @juunas I have added the aggregateexception logs. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could not figure out what the issue was. But since keyvault access works initially and fails  only after about 40/50 calls we decided to cache the secret using system.runtime.caching.memorycache

This seems to resolve the issue.

But question on keyvault access limit arises. Does keyvault have limits on simultaneous access to secrets?

Comment: We've had the same issue. When our webserver starts, we have about 6 apps that all need the key to the same DB. Worked fine until recently, then after a few tries one app worked and the other not. Even after multiple restarts.
Have you figured out more about this?

Comment: Facing similar issues.  everything working fine for months then we are getting random failures.  I added the exp retry strategy but this doesn't trip even with the HttpStatusCodeErrorDetectionStrategy.  Specifically using IConfiguration.AddAzureKeyVault(kvUriString, kvClient, new DefaultKeyvaultSecretManager).  I added an event to the retry policy and it does not fire.